# How can I send object and page id while routing without appending it in URL in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to send object and page id from one component to another component. I don't want to append these data in URL.

My Approach :-

```
this.router.navigate(['./segment-details'], { queryParams: { pageId: this.pageId, data : JSON.stringify(cardData) } });
```